# How do I set a variable of a View Controller during restoration?

Tags: ios, swift, state-restoration

In View Controller X, I am using prepareForSegue() to set a variable of a View Controller Y.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue:UIStoryboardSegue, sender:AnyObject) {
    if (segue.identifier == "mySegue") {
        let vc = segue.destinationViewController as! MyTabBarController
        vc.avar = myvar
}
```

But during restoration, when I `decodeObjectForKey()` `myvar` I cannot see how I can update the `avar` of Y

How can I set a member variable of one View Controller from another during State Restoration?

One path to a solution would be to set a flag during restoration:

```
override func decodeRestorableStateWithCoder(coder: NSCoder) {
    isRestoration = true
    super.decodeRestorableStateWithCoder(coder)
}
```

and then later in the class:

```
if isRestoration:
    // find Y View Controller which has been auto created by iOS
    // set Y.avar
```

In this approach, how would I get a reference to Y View Controller? I've given it an identifier in Storyboard but can't find any API that I can look-up the existing Y view controller.

Comment: This is problem that must be common to many Storyboard-based apps that implement restoration but call view controllers with segues. If you have toolbar-button specific needs here's a solution that doesn't involve a global: http://mikeabdullah.net/thl-ios7-diary-2-shared-toolbar-items.html

Comment: I've resorted to storing a reference to View Controller Y which, during restoration, is set by Y and then accessed by X to set `avar` of Y. I'm not posting this 'hack' as an answer.